# How to set XML file in 'Request' object (using 'setFiles' method) Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I am trying to consume a REST API (third party) and need to send a XML file along with request. I am trying to set file in the following way:

My Code:

```
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Client;
use Zend\Stdlib\Parameters;

$request = new Request();
$request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'
));
$request->setUri("<third-party-api-url>");
$request->setMethod('POST');
$request->setFiles(new Parameters(array("/path/to/xml/file.xml")));
$client = new Client();
$client->setAuth("<username>", "<password>", \Zend\Http\Client::AUTH_BASIC);
$response = $client->dispatch($request);
print_r($response->getBody());
```

When executing the above code, I am getting following response:

> [Error decoding xml body: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Premature end
>   of file.

**I guess the XML is truncating to zero length file which is causing this error. Can anyone please help me to guide how to sent file in request object?**

Thanks in advance

Dileep

Answer (score 0):

Use the client instead:

```
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setRequest($request);
    $client->setFileUpload("/path/to/xml/file.xml", 'file1');
    $response = $client->send();
```